# Excel: Adding a column at the end of a row that has been moved to a different sheet via Macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have created a Macro button that moves a row from Sheet1 to Sheet2. I want to add a column to this row when it moves. An input dialog box should appear to manually fill this new cell.

For example I have the original:

```
Number  Name   Club
 6      Dan    Chelsea
```

Then when I press the move button, the row should move to Sheet2, and an Input message should say 'Enter new club: '. I want to be able to enter 'Arsenal' for example so the output on sheet2 will be

```
Number  Name   Club      New Club
 6      Dan    Chelsea   Arsenal
```

I am using VBA. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like that transfers the data to the other sheet?

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty things up by creating a userform, but if all you want is something quick and dirty, there is a function InputBox() that will request data and assign it to a variable.  Then write the variable value to a cell.

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/inputbox-function.html

Comment: This solution is good but I can only get the column printing on the original sheet, rather than the sheet I am moving the row to. Any ideas?

Comment: https://trumpexcel.com/vba-worksheets/#Referencing-a-Worksheet-in-VBA